# Can't debug Asp.Net Core 2.1 Angular app in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1, visual-studio-2019

I just installed VS 2019 and created a new ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular project.
Haven't done anything to it and I hit the debug button to start it up in Chrome.

I received this message after Chrome loads!

Receive a exception.

Here is what I see!

[image]

Comment: Did you installed IIS debug extension during VS 2019 setup?

Comment: pretty sure, I just had to build solution. But I did that and now I get a exception in the page! I'll post an updated picture.

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that you haven't installed npm modules.

Please run `npm install` so it will install node modules.

Comment: Shouldn't that be installed for me by VS 2019 if this Angular project is built into VS as a new project template?

Comment: I am not sure :) this is why I dont like such project structure :) I prefer to separate them

Comment: huh! and where do I run this from? I tried package manager and command window and neither worked!

Comment: From folder where package.json is located